# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound error while trying running a Spring MVC code in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to run a Spring MVC code and getting the error. I have configured the request handler methods in controller class, but still getting the below error.

Error:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-
INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Sep 17, 2017 6:05:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 3323 ms
Sep 17, 2017 6:05:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound 
noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI 
[/SpringFormValidationWebApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

The URL is as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringFormValidationWebApp/
```

Below is the code:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Hello Spring MVC Web App</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-
class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

controller class:

```
package com.manjosh.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.manjosh.model.User;
import com.manjosh.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String registerPage(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "register";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/registerSuccess",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerSuccess(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    userService.createUser(user);
    return "redirect:/listUsers";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/listUsers",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView registerSuccess(ModelAndView modelAndView ){
    modelAndView.setViewName("UserList");
    List<User> userList = userService.getUserList();
    modelAndView.addObject("userList",userList);
    return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

The rest of the code is just a service layer and dao layer.
in the DAO layer the data is hard coded and there is no database connectivity.

Comment: What is your eclipse project name? It should be SpringFormValidationWebApp.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined your controller, **UserController** in **dispatcher-servlet.xml** as follows:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.manjosh.controller"></context:component-scan>
```